# Get date by mouse click, matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I want to get two dates from a calendar.
matlab functio is

```
c = calendar
```

or

```
dates = calendar; 
dates(~any(dates,2),:) = []; 
fh = figure; 
uh = uitable('parent',fh,'data',dates,'ColumnWidth',repmat({20},1,7),...
          'ColumnName',{'S','M','T','W','T','F','S'});
```

but how to get these two dates clicked by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a callback function:

```
function cell_select_callback(h, ind)
    dates = get(h, 'data');
    d = dates(ind.Indices(1), ind.Indices(2));
    if d == 0
        return
    end
    dn = datenum(2012, 12, d); % you have to have year & month here
    fprintf('cell_select_callback(): click at [%d %d] on %s\n', ind.Indices(1), ind.Indices(2), datestr(dn));
return
```

and add into uitable() arguments: `uitable(..., 'CellSelectionCallback', @cell_select_callback)`.

When pressed, cell_select_callback will print the coordinates of the click and the date, for example:
`cell_select_callback(): click at [2 3] on 04-Dec-2012`